# Matching an IP address in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

New to Scala, I've written this piece of code to match IP addresses, but results with "No Match".

```
val regex = """^(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))((\.(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|(1([0-9]{2}))|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))){3})$""".r
val i = "10.20.30.40"

def isValidIP(ip: String) = ip match {
    case regex(ip) => println(ip)
    case _ => println("No match.")
 }

isValidIP(i)
```

Result: `No match.`

I have verified that the Regex pattern works as expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your regex [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/mNJCSG/1) the full IP address. `match` requires a full string match.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I missed adding the ^ and $, I've added. But still doesn't work. As mentioned, I have verified this pattern DOES work in a regex fiddle.

Comment: You do not need `^` and `$` in the Scala code when defining the pattern because `match` will itself require full string match. Your regex is just not right. The IP address regex is well-known, use the proven patterns in your code, do not "re-invent the wheel".

Comment: Thanks again. The pattern is from a well known regex provider, I'm not re-inventing anything. It works exactly as expected when I run it here: https://regex101.com/r/tU3gC3/3 and here: http://refiddle.com/

Comment: That is some piece of ip address regex. See the canonical IP address regex [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html).

Comment: Thank you. Tried those, all result as no match. Can you just tell me, code is correct, right?

Comment: Correct, there are more than an issue with regex and `match` requiring a full string match, the problem is that `match` also requires a capturing group in the pattern. If you do not want to specify the group, you need `regex(_*) => println(ip)` to just check if the regex matches a string. Basically, the solution is https://rextester.com/MPGK88781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- An issue with your regex that [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/mNJCSG/1) the full IP address. You can use a well-known [IP address validation regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) from regular-expressions.info.
- `match` requires a full string match
- `match` also requires a capturing group in the pattern. If you do not want to specify the group, you need `regex() => println(ip)` to just check if the regex matches a string.

You can fix your code using

```
val regex = """(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)""".r
val i = "10.20.30.40"

def isValidIP(ip: String) = ip match {
    case regex() => println(ip)
    case _ => println("No match.")
}

isValidIP(i)
```

See the [Scala code demo](https://rextester.com/OBGM22856).

Comment: Perfect, that works, thank you! One last thing, in Scala is this just a pattern match or a full regex match and all the "slowness" that comes with it?

Comment: @BjornTuroque Not sure I understand the question. If the regex matches the whole string and is written properly, the only "slowness" comes from the mere fact the regex library should be loaded and match executed. If it does the work, it is the overhead you have to accept.

Comment: For this regex pattern the `_*` is not needed. If there is no capture group then `case regex()` will suffice.